# Avoiding HTTP session with legacy code in tomcat/servlet

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I'm told to use some 3rd party software that consists of a servlet and a taglib. The servlet generates search results and the taglib renders results and other interaction elements according to the servlet.

The problem is that the 3rd party solution is implemented with http sessions, means the servlet does the search, stores the result in the session, sends a redirect to the browser and on the view page (within a complete separate http request) the results from the session are shown.

I'd like to get rid of the session because this won't work with multiple tabs and has several other disadvantages. But servlet and taglib are delivered as-is and if I need something different I have to implement it on my own from scratch.

Any idea how I could achieve this to happen in one request, so that the session is not needed? In best case, without changing the code but with just a wrapper around. It could accept that the server creates a session, but I don't want the browser to depend on it.

One idea I have is using the request-dispatcher to do the servlet call and the view in one http request, but still the software uses sessions. I could then discard the session after every request. Better ideas are highly appreciated.

Of course I know, the best would be to implement it right without sessions to my requirements. But business as usual, we try to avoid spending too much time..

Thanks in advance, have a nice evening
Michel

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just forward directly to a JSP instead of the whole "redirect-and-load-from-session" nonsense?

Comment: @MattBrock I would love just to forward, but the stupid servlet does a redirect. If I would implement it, it'd be a forward or a ServletFilter instead of this redirect with session stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution, but create a **javax.servlet.Filter** which wraps **HttpServletRequest** and **HttpServletResponse** with custom ones.
Override **request.getSession()** and **response.sendRedirect()** methods in custom wrappers.

And apply your filter to the search servlet and JSPs by defining propery **<filter-mapping>** in **web.xml** file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be wrapping HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse and reimplementing HttpSession is more work than reimplementing all the code.